# Ubuntu 14.04 DVD Stuck

Tags: system-installation, software-installation

I downloaded Ubuntu Desktop to a DVD, restarted the PC with the DVD in the drawer, as instructed, the desktop came up with the Keyboard Shortcuts on the monitor and won't go anywhere. I have clicked the curser all over the screen but can't get anything to move, open, close, drag and drop or see any activity. None of the icons on the left side will open. Where do I go from here? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to try is to restart. If the problem persists, consider making a bootable USB stick instead and use that. Also verify that the DVD is fine by booting on another system or via the option when DVD boots.

If you're familiar with terminal, you can try Alt + Ctrl + F1 to see if you can run commands.